# How to build a IDE by eclipse for embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide, embedded-linux, eclipse-cdt

I want to build an IDE based on Eclipse for embedded Linux app development.

I know Eclipse CDT is good for c/c++ developing. But I need to do a lot of customization. The [GNU ARM Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/) is very close to what I need, but my target architecture is not ARM.

So, where should I start? Is CDT just enough and easy for customization? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't matter is for which ARCH you want configure this IDE. Most important is works toolchain. I have some tutorial nice Poland expert. This is in polish language but Screen is in English. May be this help You
http://bis.org.pl/systemy_wbudowane:eclipse:eclipse-1 You also find there how to setup IDE to remote debugging

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a try.